# Is there a way to do frontend web development with rust?

Tags: rust, graphql, nestjs

I've created a nodeJS backend api using nestjs mainly reason to easily setup graphQL, but when I learned about RUST I want to try using it but I already built the backend, so I'm thinking is it worth the time and effort to create a frontend from rust?

Comment: you can generate wasm code from rust

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a frontend framework for Rust called Yew https://yew.rs/